# ValueError: time data '12/16/2016' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've Imported CSV, and I'm trying to Print out Products in a CSV File that were Sold on a Weekend, but I can't Convert the Calendar Dates to Weekdays for some reason?

```
Look = open("ShopRecords.csv", "r")
#Store The Content Of The File In A ReadCSV.
ReadFile = list(csv.reader(Look))
ReadFile.pop(0)
print(ReadFile)
#Loop Through Each Line In The Record.
for Record in ReadFile:
    DateConvert = datetime.datetime.strptime(Record[2], "%d/%m/%Y")
    print(DateConvert)
#If The Line Contains Saturday, Print The Item Name, Which Is The Second Item.
    if Sat in Record:
        print(Record[1])
#If The Line Contains Sunday, Print The Item Name, Just Like If It's Saturday.
    if Sun in Record:
        print(Record[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

`%m` is the month specifier, and *16* can't be a month number, so it must be *12*, and *16* should be the date number (`%d`). So, you need the format:

```
%m/%d/%Y
```

to match *12/16/2016*.